# Clicking through a jquery dropdown menu using VBA / href=javascript:void(0)

Tags: vba

I'm trying to make a macro that logs into a website, and starts pulling reports. Problem is, as I'm parsing through the html, I see a button exactly like the one on this page: https://www.exratione.com/2011/12/a-dark-style-for-chosen-selects/

where the href is a java void and the class is a generic "chzn-single" same as that website's button.

Any suggestions?

I'm trying this but no luck:

```
Set Clickme = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("chzn-single chzn-default")(0)
Clickme.Click
```

Also, which I don't think makes much sense:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("typeSelector").Value = "Revenue"
IE.Navigate "javascript:void(0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any HTML to go with this. If it is like that which you are showing in the other link then  `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("chzn-single chzn-default")(0)` won't work because the class name is incorrect. It should be just `chzn-single`.

For the page you have linked, there are two clickable links with class of `chzn-single`.

I would use a CSS class selector to target them:

For the first:

```
IE.document.querySelector("a.chzn-single").Click
```

For the second:

```
IE.document.querySelectorAll("a.chzn-single").item(1).Click
```